# No label on fields, where change that in Backpack CRUD 5.5 Laravel 10

Tags: laravel-backpack

Can't find where I can put label on the fields generated by Backpack on Laravel 10, fresh install from 1h
Like this will be great, any idea why they don't do that by default ?

Corrected label for Backpack CRUD 5.5

[image: 1]

Have a nice day, and life
Beace

Click on the label Email and expect to be drop in the edit field of the Email
Add to move the input field into the label html
But I do that in html live editor, not in the code because I can't find where this is generated

Answer (score 1):

Indeed, that is something Backpack doesn't do by default. We have an [open issue](https://github.com/Laravel-Backpack/community-forum/issues/206) for it, and it will be done before the v6 launch.

Until then, you can use the provided [CrudField JS Library](https://backpackforlaravel.com/docs/5.x/crud-fields-javascript-api#syntax-1) to do that for your forms alone. You can do something like this:

```js
$('form [bp-field-name]').each(function(index, element) {
    var fieldName = $(element).attr('bp-field-name');

    $(crud.field(fieldName).inputWrapper).find('label').attr('for', 'field-' + fieldName);
    $(crud.field(fieldName).inputWrapper).find('input,textarea,select').filter(':first').attr('id', 'field-' + fieldName);
});
```

The above should work for 80% of all field types, but the rest might need some more tinkering. But if you absolutely HAVE TO have this, before this is done in Backpack itself... that's a good way to do it. Then when Backpack has it, you can just remove your bit of JS.